# NFS Server on OSX - squash options

Tags: docker, osx-yosemite, boot2docker, nfs

Is it possible to have no_root_squash option enabled on an OSX Yosemite NFS server?

I'm running boot2docker on OS X in Yosemite via Virtualbox (boot2docker 1.8 - from Docker Toolbox).
Due to performance issues with large mounted host-volumes, I thought about giving NFS a shot!

This is my /etc/exports

```
/Users/myuser -mapall=myuser:staff 192.168.99.100
```

This is my /etc/nfs.conf

```
nfs.server.mount.require_resv_port = 0
```

And that script is executed in boot2docker-vm

```
#!/bin/sh

sudo umount /Users

sudo mkdir -p /Users/myuser

sudo /usr/local/etc/init.d/nfs-client start
sudo mount 192.168.99.1:/Users/myuser /Users/myuser -o rw,async,noatime,rsize=32768,wsize=32768,proto=tcp,nfsvers=3
```

And inside a container I use a bash script that reads the UID and GID of a mounted volume and changes the UID and GID of a non-privileged user in order to allow read/write operations.

So far so good. But sometimes I would need to change file permissions, however sudo chmod/chown don't work because all operations are matched against my local (unprivileged) user on OSX. NFS on Linux is supporting the option no_root_squash which would perfectly solve my problems, but I'm afraid it's it's not available on OSX Yosemite.
And it's not possible to use -mapall along with -maproot.

And no, I don't want to map against root on OS X too :)

Any ideas?